# how to find by an array of ids en mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, promise

this is my code:

```
const query = await Users.findOne({_id: userId}, 'groups');

const arrayOfGroups = [];

//query.groups is an array of strings that contains id´s
await Promise.all([query.groups.forEach(async function (groupId){
   const atributtesOfGroup = await Group.findById(groupId);
   const {grade, group, career} = atributtesOfGroup;
   arrayOfGroups.push(grade + '°' + group + '\n' + career);
})]);
```

i tried to find documents by an array (query.groups) of id´s and put those into the array "arrayOfGroups"

i also tried a query with $or but it didn´t work

some ideas?
i just want an array with looks like this [grade + '°' + group + '\n' + career, grade + '°' + group + '\n' + career, grade + '°' + group + '\n' + career, ...]

Comment: Can you post the `Users` schema declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call the async function inside a loop. You can simply use the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to achieve the expected output.

```
    const user = await Users.findOne({_id: userId}, 'groups').lean()
    
    const allGroups = await Group.find({ _id: { $in: user.groups } }).lean()
    
    const arrayOfGroups = allGroups.map((group) => `${group.grade}°${group.group}'\n'${group.career}`)
    
    console.log(arrayOfGroups)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `forEach` does not return anything, you want to use the `map`-function. That returns an array of promises, so you don't need to add `[...]` as a parameter to your `Promise.all`.

You could also directly return text string in the inner function, no need to define `arrayOfGroups` upfront.